# Why does console.log not work in this case

Tags: javascript, console.log

I have this piece of code :

```
e.addEventListener('click', f => {
      console.log(`something ${f}`)
      window.location.replace("/about")
    })
```

It actually works and takes me to `/about` but doesn't console log anything

Comment: Yes because your page change.

Comment: So how do i make it actually log something because i need this info

Comment: @FilipFrank See my answer to find how to preserve logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page changes or navigates from one page to another. You might need to [Preserve Log](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#preserve-log) and it's disabled by default.

[image: preserve log]

When the above setting is enabled:

[image: enabled]

You will be able to see this way.

[image: preserved stuff]